# how to add 0 to first and 1 to rest of items in the list in binary? Python

Tags: python, list, binary, hex

`number = bin(16383)[2:]`
`dict = ([number[num:num+7].zfill(7) for num in range(0, len(number), 7)])`

i want from `['1111111', '1111111']`  to `['01111111', '11111111']`

and then convert it to hex from binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the point where you already have this list: `['1111111', '1111111']`, you can perform a list comprehension with a couple of calls to some builtins functions to achieve what you want.

Here are two ways (considering `l` to be the aforementioned list):

```
[hex(int(prefix + binary, 2)) for prefix, binary in zip('0' + (len(l) - 1) * '1', l)]
# When measuring it with timeit, and a number=1000000, it returns 3.360108 seconds
```

or

```
[hex(int('0' + binary if i == 0 else '1' + binary, 2)) for i, binary in enumerate(l)]
# When measuring it with timeit, and a number=1000000, it returns 3.048211 seconds
```

They both produce the following output:

```
['0x7f', '0xff']
```

---

**EDIT:**

Considering the link you provided, you were doing the binaries list (`l`) in a wrong way. You can do it as follows:

```
number = bin(16383)[2:]
bytes_ = [number[max(0, i - 7): i].zfill(7) for i in range(len(number), 0, -7)]
bytes_.reverse()

hex_list = [hex(int(prefix + binary, 2)) for prefix, binary in
            zip((len(bytes_) - 1) * '1' + '0', bytes_)]
# hex_list content: ['0xff', '0x7f']
```

Comment: works, but my method is not valid, it's not slicing this binary right. it should fill with 0 from the end... https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Uintvar_coding.svg

Comment: i wonder why max() is used... i - 7 shouldn't return same value?

Comment: It's used to avoid getting negative numbers. The range produces an iterator which will return the following values: `length(n) - 0, length(n) - 7, ... length(n) % 7`, excluding the zero. In case the length of the string representing the binary integer is not a multiple of 7, then when subtracting 7 from the last value returned by the `range()`, you would get negative values if not apply that `max()` function, and therefore when constructing the slice of `number`, you would not be able to get the values from the positions 0 to length(n) % 7.

Comment: Let's illustrate this with the example of the link you provided. The length of the binary number is 17. The `range()` function will return the following values: `[17, 10, 3]`. When doing the list comprehension, we get the following slices: `[10:17], [3:10]` and, thanks to that `max()` function, we also have: `[0:3]`. Otherwise, we would get: `[-4: 3]`, which would not return what we want.